# Make Intel's "Display Power Saving Technology" act faster

Tags: laptop, intel-graphics

Intel has a feature for laptops called "Display Power Saving Technology". This system adjusts the screen brightness to match the overall brightness of the picture you are seeing. While looking at a mostly white web page (like Super User) the back light is at full, but for darker pages/images/videos/etc the back light will dim. This looks a little weird when part of the screen is a light color (like the browser's control bar at the top) but the screen darkens since the screen is mostly dark. However it supposedly saves power, so why not use it, and you can selectively disable it when plugged in.

The problem is that when the brightness changes it does so *slowly* so that when you switch to a white page you can see the brightness slowly increase. This is extremely annoying. It would be fine if it immediately changed, in most cases changing to a bright screen happens suddenly, so if the brightness adjustment happens at the same time it will not be jarring.

Is there any way to make it function this way?

Comment: I would disable the feature and adjust the brightness itself this is handled by drivers and likely dependent on the load on the CPU in others it's not handled by traditional software